# wordpress access file issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I previously installed a wordpress theme and I had some problem accessing parts of it - the support for the theme fixed it, and told me that it was due to the rewrite engine needing to be switched on instead of off - I have installed a different theme and am having a similar problem, and wondered if anybody can tell me how to correct this code to switch it on?

This is the exact code in the access file - what should I change it to exactly?

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 53

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch on the rewrite engine change

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

to

```
RewriteEngine On
```

To first check if rewrite module is enabled in Apache use this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```